# Truffle : Source code in build/contracts/HelloWorld.json doesn't change after first migrate

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, visual-studio-code

build/contracts/HelloWorld.json

line 890:

"source": "// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT\r\npragma solidity 0.8.7;\r\n\r\ncontract HelloWorld{\r\n    function hello() public pure returns(string memory){\r\n        return 'hello world';\r\n    }\r\n}",

I wrote that code at start, in contracts/HelloWorld.sol ,than i changed it:

HelloWorld.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract HelloWorld{

    string public message;

    constructor(string memory _message){
        message = _message;
    }


    function hello() public view returns(string memory){
        return message; 
    }

    function setMessage(string memory _message) public{
        message = _message;
    }

}
```

migrations/2_hello_world_migration.js

```
const HelloWorld = artifacts.require("HelloWorld");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(HelloWorld,"Hello world constructor");
};
```

when im typing

1. truffle compile
2. truffle develop
3. migrate
4. let instance = await HelloWorld.deployed()
5. instance.hello()   -> returning me 'hello world', from first build/migration
6. instance.message()  -> Uncaught TypeError: instance.message is not a function
7. instance.setMessage('blah') -> Uncaught TypeError: instance.setMessage is not a function

Comment: migrate --reset doesn't help too

Comment: Try deleting or renaming the whole `build/` directory.